# android checking new data on webserver

Tags: android, webservice-client, data-transfer

I would like to build a little game app on android for 2 players. The players send strings and player 1 have to wait for the answer of player 2 and so on... So i will write and read the data to a web server. My question now how can i check in android if there is a new entry in the file on the sever? Is it the best way to check the file in an AsynkTask in Background and repeat this every 10 sek for example or is there a better way to check this, because one of the players can leave the app and continue later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using GoogleCloudMessaging to just send a notification to the phone when an opponent has taken a turn.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start